# Trasformar DatraFrame em Dicionario

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Gerei um df a partir desse dicionario:

```
data = {
    'Nomes': ['produto1','produto2']
    'Links': ['link1.html', 'link2.html']
    'Valores': ['R$00,00','R$00,00']
    'Tipos': ['brinquedo','aparelho']
}
```

Minha duvida é de como trasformar um df em um dicionario

Dataframe:

```
      Nomes       Links  Valores  Tipo
0  produto1  link1.html  R$00,00  brinquedo
1  produto2  link2.html  R$00,00  aparelho
```

Comment: Mas você já não possui o dicionário em `data`? Não basta utilizá-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metodo [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), ex:

```
df.to_dict()
```